# Installed Python Module with Pip but Cannot Import

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda, enterprise, spyder

Python 3.4

Windows 7 Enterprise

Anaconda3

Spyder 3.0.1

I was trying to install beautifulsoup4, which was successful. The original install of it had only text files in the folder and wasn't importing.

This is a picture of my pip install after deleting the original folder, which had only text files in it--no wheel or py files.

[pip install image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iILtQ.png)

It's on the installed list of modules as well. But when trying to import...

I get this message:

```
import beautifulsoup4
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-16-7e3d2e2a3c50>", line 1, in <module>
 import beautifulsoup4>

ImportError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

I'm running the above script in Spyder by the way.

I've checked my PYTHONPATH manager and have

```
C:/.../Lib/site-packages
```

in there, not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: BeautifulSoup installs as `bs4`, not `beautifulsoup4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try bs4 for the import. Also make sure to restart the cmd if you haven't already.